# Как спрятать последний ul внутри ul

Tags: css

Есть список категорий, вложенность которого может достигать до 10 категорий
Возможно ли с помощью css скрыть последний `ul` внутри первого `ul`

```css
.test:last-child ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="test">
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="nav-link">1 категория</a>
    <div class="pluse">+</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/" class="nav-link">Подкатегория</a>
        <div class="pluse">+</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/" class="nav-link">Под категория под категории</a>
            <div class="pluse">+</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Пробовал для главного `ul` задавать класс `test` и через псевдокласс `:last-child` скрывать, но скрывается все меню.
Он скрывает вторую вложенность, возможно ли найти последний `ul` элемент внутри 'ul.test'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите последнему тегу li класс "hide"
CSS

```
.hide{
  display:none;  
}
```

укажите класс class="hide"

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="nav-link">1 категория</a>
    <div class="pluse">+</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/" class="nav-link">Подкатегория</a>
        <div class="pluse">+</div>
        <ul>
          <li class="hide">
            <a href="/" class="nav-link">Под категория под категории</a>
            <div class="pluse">+</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Если вы указываете корневому ul некий класс, то необходимо через javascript искать последний li для скрытия.

Comment: К сожалению нет возможности вручную подставить класс для последнего `ul` все меню генерируется автоматически, и при генерации нет возможности отследить последний `ul`

Comment: В любом случае придется как-то определять последний элемент, и скорей всего это будет через javascript. Иначе придется писать что-то типа:

 .test ul li ul:last-of-type {
    color: green; 
}

Для каждого уровня.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не совсем то что Вы имели в виду.. Но всё же..

```css
ul:last-child ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="test">
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="nav-link">1 категория</a>
    <div class="pluse">+</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/" class="nav-link">Подкатегория</a>
        <div class="pluse">+</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/" class="nav-link">Под категория под категории</a>
            <div class="pluse">+</div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/" class="nav-link">Под категория под категории</a>
                <div class="pluse">+</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```